# set array of data into mobx array show proxy objects

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm using react js with mobx and I get data from api.
the data I get is array of objects.
when I set the data into mobx variable then I see array of proxy objects(not sure what the proxy says). I'm trying just to set the array of objects I get from api into mobx variable.

my store

```
class UserStore {
@persist @observable token = null
@observable tasks = []
@observable done = false

@persist @observable email = ''

constructor() {

}
@action
getTasks = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await Api.getTasks()
        console.log('getTasks',response.tasks)
        this.tasks = response.tasks
        console.log('my new tasks',this.tasks)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

[image]

as you can see here in the first block('black') the data i get from api, then i set the respnse.tasks into this.tasks.

```
 this.tasks = response.tasks
  console.log('my new tasks',this.tasks)
```

Comment: Is this code not working for you? MobX 5 uses Proxies under the hood, so that in itself is nothing strange.

Comment: the code is working but I can't use this.tasks and display the tasks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how you want to observe the data.

> "I'm trying just to set the array of objects I get from api into mobx variable"

is not really your end-goal.

If you want your observers to:

- **option a**: react when the array reference change
  = No care for values in the array.
  Use `@observable.ref tasks`.
- **option b**: react when the references of each value in the array change
  = No care for the individual objects properties.
  Use `@observable.shallow tasks`.
- **option c**: react on the individual objects properties too
  = Make everything observable, references and object properties
  Use `@observable tasks` like you do.

Like indicated in the comments, mobx5 is using Proxy and some behaviour might differ compared to previous version.

More info: [Mobx arrays](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html), [Mobx decorators](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/modifiers.html), [shallow observability](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/modifiers.html#shallow-observability)

Note: you would need to give more details if this does not help you, like your react component code.

Answer (score 59):

You can convert proxy to JS:

```js
import { toJS } from 'mobx'

// example
toJS(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `toJS` was not working because I had a class with a variable with the type of another class. So, I needed to create new objects from the JSON:

```
parsedArray.map(
  (a) =>
    new MyObj1({
      id: a.id,
      myObj2: new MyObj2({
        label: a.label,
      }),
      title: a.title,
    })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you run debugger, stop the debugger. It messes the mobx's flow.